Background image blinking after i click on navigations
I'm having a problem with background image in CSS blinking after I click on navigation bars. If I don't click it my background is fine but when I click it it disappears for a few seconds and it comes back. Also I can't put it in body because I have paddings everywhere my image doesn't fully expand. So I put it in the html. I think it just have delay cause the page is loading?  Here the code, please I need some help! Thanks!
html{

font-family:Verdana;
text-align: center;
background-color:  #cccccc;
padding-left: 100px;
padding-right: 100px;
background-image: url('photo.jpg');

}

I tried to put it into the body but it didn't work, I tried to position it to absolute that didn't worked either.

Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
